# Divs created in Javascript don't appear

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making [an rgb guesser game for school](http://www.rgbchallenge.com/), and the stretch goal I'm trying to reach is "making divs in javascript". For some reason, my divs aren't appearing when I'm making them. Here's the javascript code snippers

```
dothething()
function dothething(){
  divs = MakeDivs(4);
  var randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
  WinningDiv = divs[randomcolor];
}

function MakeDivs(X){
  for(i = 0;i<=X;i++){
    var div = (document.createElement("div"));
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.height = "100px";
    div.width = "125px";
  }
  console.log(divs)

  var container = document.getElementById("container")
  container.appendChild(div);

  return divs
}
```

and here's some filler html

```
<body>
  <div> FillerDiv</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `divs` will be undefined for a start. A) You've defined it in the scope of that first function and b) You didn't assign it properly with a var or let

Comment: You append only once the var div to the container. You should put it in the loop.

Comment: You pretty much just appended one div

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to append the div to the container.

```
var div = (document.createElement("div"));
div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
div.height = "100px";
div.width = "125px";
container.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed `container.appendChild(div);` inside the loop. In your original code, you have just appended the last div.

```
function MakeDivs(X){
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var divs = [];
for(i = 0;i<=X;i++){
    var div = (document.createElement("div"));
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.height = "100px";
    div.width = "125px";
    divs.push(div);
    container.appendChild(div);
}
console.log(divs);     
return divs;
}
```

Comment: divs is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure why `divs` is getting returned

Comment: I just tried this, and although I'm sure this will help in the future, I still can't get the divs to appear. They're not appearing on the page.

Comment: Have you tried adding `div.style.border = '1px solid'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `append` inside the loop and use a correct control to append your DIV. Also in case you want to return your DIVs elements, add them to array and return them as in below code:

```
function MakeDivs(X){
var divs = [];
for(i = 0;i<=X;i++){
    var div = (document.createElement("div"));
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.height = "100px";
    div.width = "125px";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    divs.push(div);
}
console.log(divs)
return divs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing array of `divs`.

Incorrect way to apply width and height.

```
div.height = "100px";
    ^

div.width = "125px";
    ^
```

```js
dothething()

function dothething() {
  divs = MakeDivs(4)
  var randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  WinningDiv = divs[randomcolor]
}

function MakeDivs(X) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var divs = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= X; i++) {
    var div = (document.createElement("div"));
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.width = "125px";
    container.appendChild(div);
    
    divs.push(div);
  }
  //console.log(divs)

return divs
}
```

```css
#container div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
FillerDiv
<div id='container'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is helpful for you. Without defining `HTML tag ID` you are getting Id `container`. The variable should be defined before use anywhere. 
You missed `divs array` to define. You should add every `div` in the loop.

```js
dothething()
function dothething(){
var divs = MakeDivs(4)
var randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
WinningDiv = divs[randomcolor]
}

function MakeDivs(X){
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var divs = [];
for(i = 0;i<=X;i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.height = "100px";
    div.width = "125px";
    div.innerHTML = 'Test'+i;
    divs.push(div);
    container.appendChild(div);
}
console.log(divs);
return divs
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container"> FillerDiv</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) for creating a block which contains all the colored divs. I've refactored a little bit your code. You can check the solution on jsfiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/2zcg59sd/ or you can run the snippet here.

```js
dothething()

function dothething(){
var divs = MakeDivs(4) ;
document.getElementById("randomColors").appendChild(divs);
}


function MakeDivs(X){
  var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for(i = 0;i<=X;i++){
      var randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random()*900000) + 100000;
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 

      newDiv.style.borderRadius = "50%";
      newDiv.style.height = "100px";
      newDiv.style.float = "left";
      newDiv.style.width = "125px";
      newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomcolor;

      docFragment.appendChild(newDiv);
  }


  return docFragment
}
```

```html
<div> FillerDiv</div> 
<div id="randomColors"></div>
```